# Undefined control sequence: bfseries

Tags: xetex, mactex, mac

I am trying to recompile a file I have not worked with for quite some time, on a new computer with a fresh new install of MacTeX-2015.

I get the following error which I couldn't make sense out of.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\bfseries ->\headingfont
\color {headercolor}
l.356 {\bfseries
\xdef\@bfseriesname{\f@series}}
```

I get that something above is either misspelled or not defined, but the file should work, I have not tinkered with it since I last updated and compiled it (it's my resume). To make the matter more interesting there is no line 356 in my document, the file is much shorter than that. The (presumably) relevant line in the style (cls) file is:

```
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
```

**EDIT:** Regarding the comments that below about the redefining `\bfseries` , well it's from a [template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv) I have used, so it's not entirely my own initiative. As I said above, it did work before (almost a year ago) so I am not sure what changed since then.

**EDIT2:** If it is indeed `\headingfont` that is undefined then the relevant bit should be the following:

```
\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{Helvetica Neue}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{Helvetica Neue UltraLight}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold}
```

I do have the fonts installed and the pdf preview shows me the fonts in appropriate sizes.

Comment: The undefined control sequence is `\headingfont`. A minimal example is necessary. The line number refers to a loaded package, I guess.

Comment: you seem to have reformatted the error message? which makes it hard to understand, th eundefined command is not `\bfseries` it is `\headingfont` (if that was where the linebreak was) or `\color` if it broke after `\color`.

Comment: Redefining `\bfseries` is not, in my opinion, in any way wise. It will come back and bite you with strengthened jaws and sharpened teeth.

Comment: It is hard express how bad an idea this is. If you redefine `\bfseries`, this will also change `textbf`! The normal idea is to abstract from the commands like `bfseries`: i.e., define `\headingfont` to be `<whatever>` and use that command as appropriate, not redefine "basic" font commands in terms of the abstracted, high-level commands you use in your document.

Comment: That template in particular has given me many headaches, as a helper, not a user. The original repo doesn't even exist any more.

Comment: @Johannes_B noticed that as well, pity that the original isn't around anymore.. I wouldn't mind doing something similar from scratch myself, but the class file structure is rather intimidating; lots of commands I am not sure about

Comment: I just downloaded the template and it runs fine. No undefined commands.

Comment: Would you mind visiting our chat and tell me why you chose thise template? I am interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have messed up the order of definitions in the class, in an attempt to modify and "tidy up" the class file. So that the definition of \headingfont comes after it's first appearance... Serves me right for not doing my reading in due time.

My thanks go to Johannes_B, for figuring out whats wrong and helping out over the chat.